# I am building a Photo editing app in flutter which can apply built in photo filters on an image picked from gallery

Tags: flutter, filter, photo, editing

I have written the code by taking help from official documentation of each plugin. Inspite of that I am getting errors mentioned below. Can anyone help what is the issue ?

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/semantics.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:photofilters/photofilters.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageLib;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;
  String fileName;
  Filter _filter;
  List<Filter> filters = presetFiltersList;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    fileName = basename(pickedFile.path);
    var image = imageLib.decodeImage(pickedFile.readAsBytesSync());
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          getImage();
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PhotoFilterSelector(
                  image: _image,
                  filters: filters,
                  filename: fileName,
                  loader: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                ),
              ));
        },
        label: Text("+"),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.print,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ERRORS :

1. The method 'readAsBytesSync' isn't defined for the type 'PickedFile'.
   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'readAsBytesSync'.
2. 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.
   Try adding the missing arguments.

3.The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

4. The argument type 'File' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image'.

Answer (score 4):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Use `imageLib.Image _image;` not `File _image;` 
Step 2: Use `_file.readAsBytesSync()`

```
 File _file = File(pickedFile.path);
_image = imageLib.decodeImage(_file.readAsBytesSync());
```

Step 3: `onPressed` need to use `async` and `await`

```
onPressed: () async{
          await getImage();
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/semantics.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:photofilters/photofilters.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageLib;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  imageLib.Image _image;
  //File _image;
  String fileName;
  Filter _filter;
  List<Filter> filters = presetFiltersList;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  Future getImage() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    fileName = basename(pickedFile.path);
    File _file = File(pickedFile.path);
    _image = imageLib.decodeImage(_file.readAsBytesSync());
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        //_image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () async{
          await getImage();
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PhotoFilterSelector(
                  title: Text("Photo Filter Example"),
                  image: _image,
                  filters: filters,
                  filename: fileName,
                  loader: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                ),
              ));
        },
        label: Text("+"),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.print,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I wrote this code but after applying the filter there is no option of saving the image in gallery, when I touch the tick mark button it goes back to first screen. Can you please tell how to resolve that ? Also how can I use my custom filters which are in the form of DNG files?

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you.

Comment: For your additional question, could you please post to a new question, so more people can help you. thanks.